# ManyToMany relation, orphanRemoval

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities:

- Locus
- Reference

On each Locus we can defined many different References, and a Reference can be used by Many Locus. Then I'have a ManyToMany relation.

But, in my case the Reference is nothing if not linked by a Locus, I don't want keep it in my BDD.

List of try:

- Relation owned by Reference:

  - orphanRemoval in the ReferenceEntity (on the owned side): delete the Locus
  - orphanRemoval in the LocusEntity (on the InversedSide): do nothing
- Relation owned by Locus:

  - orphanRemoval in the ReferenceEntity (on the InversedSide): do nothing
  - orphanRemoval in the LocusEntity (on the owned side): delete the Reference although used by other Locus

Reference.php

```
/**
 * Reference
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reference")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ReferenceRepository")
 */
class Reference
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Locus", inversedBy="references")
     */
    private $locus;

    public function addLocus(Locus $locus)
    {
        if (!$this->locus->contains($locus)) {
            $this->locus->add($locus);
            $locus->addReference($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLocus(Locus $locus)
    {
        if ($this->locus->contains($locus)) {
            $this->locus->removeElement($locus);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocus()
    {
        return $this->locus;
    }
```

Locus.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\LocusRepository")
 */
class Locus extends GeneticEntry
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Reference", mappedBy="locus", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $references;

    public function addReference(Reference $reference)
    {
        $this->references->add($reference);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeReference(Reference $reference)
    {
        if ($this->references->contains($reference)) {
            $this->references->removeElement($reference);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReferences()
    {
        return $this->references;
    }
```

Comment: You can try to make an event onLocusDeleted, so that inside you check if its related references contains a non related one else, if exists then remove it

Comment: Yes it's true, I've not think to do it, I don't know why but I just pass a long time to search and try a native Doctrine way to do that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone has find a Doctrine solution meanwhile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment I've choose to use an EventListener on postUpdate event, I test the ArrayCollection, if empty, I delete the Entity:

ReferenceListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\Reference;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class ReferenceListener
{
    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $object = $args->getObject();
        if (!$object instanceof Reference) {
            return;
        }

        // If the Reference have no Locus and no Chromosomes, delete it
        if ($object->getLocus()->isEmpty() && $object->getChromosomes()->isEmpty()) {
            $args->getEntityManager()->remove($object);
            $args->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a Doctrine lifecycle EventSubscriber and realised you have to 'cover' more than postUpdate. For instance your listener won't be triggered if all the Locus and Chromosomes of a given Reference are removed via the ORM, even though that Reference will end up with `$object->getLocus()->isEmpty()` and `$object->getChromosomes()->isEmpty()` both true. You also need a `preRemove()` method with the same logic except it should accept `Locus` and `Chromosome` as `$object` class, and `$object` vars in the second condition should be replaced by `$reference = $object->getReference();`.